# excel vba hide filter arrows?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

i am using the following script to filter my rows based on a cell value.
the script works fine however I am trying to get rid of those annoying filter arrows from displaying. I have tried the following but they still show:

```
Sub DateFilter()
Dim nRow As Range
Dim toSearch As Range
    'hide dialogs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'filter for records that have June 11, 2012 in column 3


    If ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value = "" And ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Else
    Set toSearch = Range("A9:E13")
    'detect row that matches criteria:
    Set nRow = toSearch.Find(ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value)
    If Not (nRow Is Nothing) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E9:A13").AutoFilter Field:=nRow.Column, VisibleDropDown:=False, Criteria1:="*" & nRow.Value & "*"
    End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

please can someone show me where I am going wrong. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to clear the filter before making the drop-downs non-visible?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes first thing I tried

Comment: I believe you need to set the `VisibleDropDown` parameter for each field that you want to hide the arrows on.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801531/hiding-autofilter-arrows-not-working

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but someone may be able to use this bit of code.

```
Range("A3:H3").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=7, VisibleDropDown:=False
```

This will put filter dropdown arrows from "A3:H3" for those people who have multiple header rows.

It will then remove the dropdown arrow from the 4th & 7th columns (D & G) so that the only columns that are filtered are A-C and E-F and H.

Hope this clears up some questions about unique filters.